# Check if multiple downloads are complete?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

my app requires to download like 10 images when it first starts up. so once all the images are downloaded it should move on to the next activity.but when it finishes downloading the first image it crashes.I have no idea why.ive attached the code of the Receiver and Logcat below.thank you in advance.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {
                        testtv.setText("Download Complete");

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

LOGCAT

```
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): Process: com.id.imagedownloader, PID: 11857
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.id.imagedownloader (has extras) } in com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity$1@41bc2aa8
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:776)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:50)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:766)
11-03 19:49:01.660: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException at line 50.

Comment: use Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ it´ll download and cache images on it´s own

Comment: @kristyWelsh line 50 is `Cursor c = dm.query(query);` i got the code for the broadcast receiver from http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

Comment: are you loading your dm instance properly (as shown in the onClick method in the link you posted)?